# Disable window scrolling leaving the scrollbar visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I disable window scrolling but leave scrollbar visible?

I usually use `overflow:hidden;`. But when I do that the window scrollbar disappears. I'm looking for a way to disable scrolling but keep the scrollbar visible.

Comment: can I ask why you would want to do this? From a user experience standpoint, if there is a widely known element meant to convey the ability to scroll, and I wasn't able to scroll, that would be pretty frustrating.

Comment: @NeilS thanks. I agree but in my case, I've got several canvas elements which will be created dynamically at the bottom of the page and passed on to the server as base64. All these happens using an onClick event. So I want to keep all those behind scene and prevent user seen them. So I'm looking for a way to disable scrolling but keep the scrollbar visible for that split second.

Comment: you can wrap all those in a hidden div and when the load is finish you fix it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content in a div that has max-height:100% and overflow:hidden. Body tag needs the overflow:auto or overflow-y:scroll.

Comment: Thanks. Setting `max-height:100%` will hide the div. I need it to be visible at all times. I just want to stop the scroll. If I could let it be hidden I would have done a `display:none`